# How to carry a MTB on one's backpack?

Tags: mountain-bike

Sometimes I want to ascend a steep (say, 50%) slope, where is impossible to ride and awkward to push/pull the bike.

I tried various ways of carrying the bike:

- Lifting it just 10 cm above the ground - good for very short sections
- Lifting it with one hand to shoulder height - good for short sections; the arm gets tired quicky
- Holding it above my neck with two hands; the arms get numb quickly
- Putting it on my backpack; the back starts to ache at random places, as if warped

I imagine the last idea, with resting the bike on the backpack, is the only usable one for long sections (say, 30-60 minutes walking). Am I right?

Which way can I secure my bike on my backpack, so the back ache (and supposedly damage) is minimized?

---

Update: I had a half-full 35-litre backpack at the day I had this problem. I am willing to fill my pack with light bulky stuff if needed, but I don't want a bigger pack: 35 L seems enough for maximal journeys I want to do; any bigger and it starts to be annoying.

Comment: Some questions that arise: what type of frame does your bike have? How big and how full is your backpack? Depending on that, the options may vary a bit.

Comment: With a decent trekking backpack you can strap your bike to it. There's a race called Yak Attack, where practically all major ascents are done this way.

Comment: @BenediktBauer A diamond frame maybe; is that a type? I am sorry but I don't understand what you mean by "type". Anyway [here](http://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/TrekBicycleProducts/75662) is a picture.

Comment: Yes, diamond or other form is basically the information I was asking for.

Comment: Also, would this question provide some help: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/16562/5271 ?

Comment: I sometimes roll the bike along on the back wheel. Its only really useful for short sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My friends and I have hiked a lot while carrying our bikes. What I've found that works best is:

- go to the non drive side of the bike
- drop the non drive side pedal down
- left hand on the left fork lower
- right hand on the non drive side crank arm
- lift whole bike and place bottom tube behind your neck

This works because:

- bike is central on top of you and you can easily remove one or both hands whenever necessary
- you don't get dirty because the drive side is away from you

To lift the bike, your hands should go to the two red spots:

[image]

Also see [How to shoulder a bike?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16562/how-to-shoulder-a-bike)

Comment: Perfect! Stay away from the rotors. Stay away from the chain. Clamp the seat to your shoulder (because of the backpack shoulder stripes, this is not painful). Support the bike down tube if not extremely muddy. Profit.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a question we can answer for you.

Practice lashing the bike to the pack until you get something balanced.
You have front wheel up, front wheel down, and sideways.

A climbing style pack will have more lash points.

Put the weight high so you can lean forward and get the weight over your hips without bending a lot.

Comment: Lashing the bike on you would not be a safe idea. The possibility of strong wind making you lose balance is always present in steep mountains. Being able to "dissengage" quickly is vital.

Comment: @cherouvim A bike has no more frontal area than large pack with ropes, tent, sleeping bag, and other climbing gear that go up mountains all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Different method - don't carry it at all.   Instead use the bike as a glorified walking stick.

Rotate the seat so its pointing about 45 degrees off to the right.  Stand on the left side of the bike.  Lean the bike towards you so its about 5 degrees off vertical and rest your right hip/butt cheek on the side of the saddle.  This keeps the left-side pedal clear of your right ankle/shin.

Hold the handlebars like you're riding normally, and use the brakes to hold the bike still while you step.

If things go wrong, you can simply release your hands and the bike will be free of you, not tied on.

I feel that this will be fine for any angle from 20 up to ~35 degrees of climb.  Less than 20 degrees and you could be riding it.  More than 40 degrees is not really walking, its climbing.

Finally, your bike is for riding not carrying.  Can you find an easier, albeit longer way around?